# How to record the stream of video chat application using socket.io peerjs in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

I am building a video chat app, where **multiple** users can join the same room and chat with each other,

want to add a functionality if users want they can **RECORD THE ENTIRE CHAT WITH AUDIO AND VIDEO WITH MULTIPLE USERS**

I am using socket.io, peerjs packages with Node JS

I need help on how to add this functionality
any resource or code snippets will help

`navigator.mediaDevices .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true, }) .then((stream) => { /// some socket and peerjs code to show videos of users connected on the same ROOM });`

I am unable to find how to record the entire chat with multiple users on it.

if I am trying to use
`let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);`
and pass the stream then it only records individual's video
**I want a single video recording the entire chat with all the percipients on it like on zoom**
how to implement this functionality, please help by giving some suggestion, approach or resource

Comment: Have  you find the solution for it

Answer (score 0):

using MediaRecorder API, you will have to display the differente video you receive in a canvas and then send this canvas to mediaRecorder.

For audio a quick search will lead you to many exemple with audioContext.